# Google Analytics Experiments: New site version

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

We have a site running for a few years.
We have set goals and conversion on Analytics, and it works really nice.

We are developing a totally new and revamped website.
We want to test the new version with Google Analytics Experiments, to let's say 25% of the visitors.

The URL structure will be:

**Home:**
Original - http://oursite.com/
New - http://oursite.com/new/

**Signup page:**
Original - http://oursite.com/signup
New - http://oursite.com/new/signup

**Success page:**
Original - http://oursite.com/success
New - http://oursite.com/new/success

Can we make this kind of test with Google Analytics Experiments ?
Is Google Analytics the right tool to make this kind of experiment ? (if not, can you please recommend)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GA Experiments are what you use when you want to test things like conversion rates between two designs. Yes, this is a fairly simple scenario and GA should be able to handle it.

There are several ways you could go about this.. how you want to structure it is up to you, but one suggestion is to setup a goal with funnel to match for /signup as step 1 and /success as step 2. The goal will be for just that URL so that it will count for both versions of signup and success.  Then the AB Experiment would be oursite.com/ as the original and oursite.com/new/ as the variation.

Comment: Since the success page (conversion goal) it's the same for both versions, should i place the GA experiment snippet code in that page ?